# Remove Compare Products

Tags: magento-1.9, compare

I am using **theme254k** in Magento 1. I would like to remove **Compare Products** section of side bar of Category Page. How can I do that ??

I found below code in catalog.xml

```
<default>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="right">
            <!--<block type="core/template" name="left.permanent.callout" template="callouts/left_col.phtml">
                <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_left_callout.jpg</src></action>
                <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Our customer service is available 24/7. Call us at (555) 555-0123.</alt></action>
                <action method="setLinkUrl"><url>checkout/cart</url></action>
            </block>-->
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" after="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="side.menu" as="sideMenu" translate="label" before="-">
                <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav2" template="page/html/sidemenu.phtml"/>
            </block>

        </reference>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map"><label>Site Map</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" /><title>Site Map</title></action>
        </reference>
        <block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template" />
    </default>
```

[image]

I removed below code from above code

```
<block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" after="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
```

But **Compare Product** is not removed.

[image]

Comment: Magento 1 or Magento 2?

Answer (score 4):

there are many ways, simply use following from page where you want to remove

**app/code/design/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout/local.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_category_layered>
<reference name="left">
          <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />

     </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But your solution is not working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove compare product from category page as below.

```
1. app/design/frontend/[Your Theme]/layout/catalog.xml
```

find the block, and added code

```
<catalog_category_default>
<!-- either "left" or "right" -->
  <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
        </reference>
</catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
<!-- either "left" or "right" -->
      <reference name="right">
                <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
            </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

and if this not work for you, then open your current theme local.xml file avilable at

```
app/design/frontend/[Your Theme]/layout/local.xml
```

add this code.

```
    <catalog_category_default>
<!-- either "left" or "right" -->
  <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
        </reference>
</catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
<!-- either "left" or "right" -->
      <reference name="right">
                <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
            </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dhiren Vasoya for your reply. But you solution is not working. Thanks